# Is it appropriate to respond to a comment in the body of an answer

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer to a question. I received a comment to my post, that disagrees with my answer. But, I feel this person is wrong, and I feel my answer was correct. I feel this is the reason for the downvote my answer received (possibly from the person who left the comment).

I would like to respond to this comment, but I need to provide some example (HTML) code in my response, and I think it would be better to respond to the comment by including it in my answer rather that by posting another comment.

Would this be appropriate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, feel free to edit your answer any time it will make the answer better.

If somebody leaves a comment that has valid (or at least reasonable) feedback or criticism, it's entirely OK to edit your answer to clarify whatever may have led to their reaction.

Note that the person commenting won't be notified automatically if you edit the post, so you may also want to @mention them in a comment later, referring them to the edits and asking if that cleared things up for them. This has the added benefit of allowing them to change their vote (if they want to on their own - never try to coerce or badger somebody into voting a particular way), since after a post has been edited, votes can be changed.

Comment: I have edited the question to add additional information. But I would also like to edit it again to provide a response specifically to this comment. My concern is that to others, and the original poster, this response is not (at least not directly) related to the original question/answer ... I suppose that depends on how I word it.

Comment: @KevinFegan while it's up to you what you want to include in a post, I would tend to avoid putting responses to comments within the answer, unless the information you're adding is a general improvement to the post.